# ECLIPSE REMOTE SYSTEM EXPLORER recursive text search

Tags: eclipse-rse

I'm running *Eclipse PDT Helios* under *Windows seven* and hosting a debian server within a *VirtualBox VM*, for development purposes.

I'm struggling with the **RSE** as I can run a text search on the remote file system, but the obtained result is not satisfactory:
I get only the content of the files owned by "root" (as per the SFTP connection setup), but not the other files contents.

For sure, a solution could be to own all files by root within the remote system, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Is there any particular setting to be adjusted within Eclipse to state it must search for all files, not only the ones owned by "root" ?

## EDIT

RSE view shows up the file tree, and I can open/edit/save them. But I can't browse any of these directories in the remote search window.

Comment: I could never get RSE remote search to work on a SFTP file system and I have been using Eclipse for a while now, could you expand on how you have it setup?

Comment: Sorry I can't elaborate that 3 years later than solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by setting differently the ssh user in Eclipse and permissions in the VM.